# PythonQT, QMenu update QActions

Tags: python, qt, qmenu, qaction, pythonqt

I've got the following code which was working well before I updated utils._DATA twice. Utils._DATA is dictionary.

```py
class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        super(SystemTrayIcon, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, self.parent)
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)

        self.actions = {}

        self.Update()

    def Update(self):
        self.menu.clear()
        self.actions.clear()
        for key in utils._DATA:
            self.actions[key] = self.menu.addAction(key)
            self.actions[key].triggered.connect(partial(utils.copy, key))

        self.setContextMenu(self.menu)
```

But if I call self.Update() after editing utils._DATA (second, third time etc), QActions exist but do nothing.

How can I update QMenu with working QActions in it?

Utils.copy is next:

```py
def copy(identificator):
    try:
        clipboard.copy(_DATA[identificator])
        return 0
    except:
        raise Exception('Cannot copy to clipboard')
```

I'm updating like _DATA = load(), where load() read specific file and convert it to dict. So in simple form it's

```py
_DATA[file.readline()] = some_string
```

Update data works good, even QActions in my QMenu updating good, but their trigger does nothing!

Comment: Try to debug by adding a very simple trigger function that prints that it has been called and see what happens.

Comment: @ababak triggers do nothing as well, I replaced utils.copy with simple function that just prints _DATA, works only before updating dictionary. Does it matter work I with that dict or not, should I try debug without _DATA?